# Clojure - How To Properly Mount State In Unit Tests

Tags: mongodb, testing, clojure, luminus, monger

I'm attempting to test some database operations in a luminus app with the Monger database library.

Ideally, I'd like the following to work. I've stripped out some of the irrelevant code.

Test File:

```
(ns app.test.handler
  (:require [clojure.test :refer :all]
            [app.db.core :as db]))

(testing "create user"
    (db/create-user "test" "test" "test")
    (is (true? true))))
```

DB File

```
(defstate db*
  :start (-> env :database-url mg/connect-via-uri)
  :stop (-> db* :conn mg/disconnect))

(defstate db
  :start (:db db*))


(defn create-user
  "Creates a new user with a token"
  [username email password]
  (let [user {:username username
              :email email
              :password (hashers/derive password)
              }]
  (mc/insert db "user" user)))
```

This doesn't work, and gives me the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: mount.core.DerefableState cannot be cast to com.mongodb.DB
```

From what I can tell, this isn't mounting the DB correctly, so it can't call the database operations. I tried to move this mounting code to the test, but still received the same error.

I did get this to work:

Test file

```
(def db (mg/connect-via-uri "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/worldbuilder"))

(testing "create user"
     (let [user {:username "test"
                 :email "test"
                 :password "test"
                 :token "test"
                 }]
    (mc/insert (:db db) "user" user)
    (is (true? true))))
```

But this requires me to re-write the operation in my test defeating the purpose. If I leave the connection above, but call the db/create-user I get the same state error.

I'd like to be able to pass that connection defined in my test file into my other database file. Is there I way I can do this and get it to override how it's being set there?

Comment: It seems you've forgotten to start a resource via `(mount/start #'db)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should setup stateful bits in your tests by using `clojure.test/use-fixtures`, for example:

```
(ns app.test.handler) ; rest of ns block omitted for clarity

(defn start-states [f]
  (mount.core/start)
  (f))

(clojure.test/use-fixtures :once start-states)
```

This will start the database before any tests are run.

See links for how to customize this: https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.test/use-fixtures

Here is also some more flavour reading about clojure.test (from the creator himself): https://stuartsierra.com/2016/05/19/fixtures-as-caches

Comment: Not sure what I'm doing wrong, adding this is gives me a null pointer exeception and the error could not start [#'app.db.core/db*] due to
 at mount.core$up$fn__273.invoke(core.cljc:92)

Comment: @newBieDev do you have more stack trace or sample code?

Comment: Hi Ray, did you end up resolving this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Hey @JeelShah, the commenter never replied with the new error. I've used this approach in my work projects

Comment: Thanks Ray! I appreciate the response :D I wasn't expecting it since the post is old. :P